# c++ noob questions, &ss !ss or ss.X

Tags: c++, function

Sorry, this is a very noob question. I'm a fresh c++ student...

I am trying to understand a c++ code I found online for a space shooter like game. I want to use it for my project. The hero shoots arrows to an enemy. It has this &ss, ss.X and !ss but I don't know what they mean. What does the . between variables mean? And what does &ss mean? Would you please share any topic or lesson related to this? Or do you know what term these are called?  I'm trying to search it on google, but I don't know the right keyword.

This is when the monster hits the hero. This is a function inside a class of my monster.

```
class monster
{
private:
int x;
int y;
public:
int X()  { return x; } 
int Y()  { return y; }

void Collision(Hero &ss) 
   {
   if(((x >= ss.X()) && (x <= ss.X() + 5)) && ((y >= ss.Y()) && (y <= ss.Y() + 2)))
   { 
   ss.Damage(); //a function under my hero class which will decrease hero energy
   gotoxy(x,y); printf(" "); 
   x = rand()%74 + 3; 
   y = 4;
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any basic C++ tutorial will cover all of this for you.

Comment: All of those are *operators*. Look up an operator list for C++...

Comment: you shouldn't post a question without knowing anything about C++. would be better for you to check through some tutorials for beginners.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you really expect to understand these symbols by just reading on stackoverflow, you'd be deluded! I can tell you, the first one is a reference to `s`, the second is the NOT operator on `s`, and the third one is accessing a member of `s`. Did that teach you anything? With no background, it's pointless. You have to work hard to understand C++. Coding is hard and needs hard work. Pick a book and start reading!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to start to c++ basic tutorials. Take a look to this page: [https://www.learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/)

&ss means that your object of type Hero is passed as reference. Understanding you're a beginner in C++, you don't know what means pass by reference. So let's see an example:

If you declare your function as void Collision(Hero ss) { } and then use it in your main() { }.

```
void Collision(Hero ss) {}

int main() 
{
  Hero MyHero;
  Collision(MyHero);
}
```

This means that inside your Collision method ss parameter will be a copy of your MyHero object. So any modification you will do to ss, MyHero will not be modified.

But if you declare void Collision(Hero &ss) {}:

```
void Collision(Hero &ss) {}

int main() 
{
  Hero MyHero;
  Collision(MyHero);
}
```

This means ss will be Myhero object. This implies any modification you will do to ss will modify MyHero object.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the examples and explanation. This is the part that I'm still confused about in my class. I just started c++ so excuse my noobness. So these (&ss) are just parameters, not special keywords.

Answer (score 1):

`Hero& ss` is passing an object of the class `Hero` by reference (pass by reference is the term to search for). This means more or less that the adress of the object is passed into this function, and since it's not a const reference, you can call all methods of the class (const and non-const).

`ss.X` is actually `ss.X()` and is a call of the method `X()` in `Hero`, which returns the value of the member variable `x`.

I don't see any `!ss` in your example, but that would call an operator in `Hero` that returns a boolean value, and the result would be `true` if the returned value is `false` (! being the not operator).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll definitely read about "pass by reference".